# Changing image while clicking/unclicking button

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, button

Can somebody tell me how to dynamically change the image of a button while clicking it?

#### My code:

`$('.gamebox_minimap_plus').click(function() {
        $(this).css("background-image","url('gfx/plus2.png')");
    });`

It works after a click, not while clicking, and does not come back to plus1.png after I stop clicking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to use the mousedown and mouseup events.

[jQuery .mousedown()](http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/)

[jQuery .mouseup()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseup/)

In addition if you are using jQuery 1.7 or higher you should begin using/getting use to the [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) methods.

Answer (score 1):

Use mousedown and mouseup insead of click. Like this:

```
$('.gamebox_minimap_plus').mousedown(function() { $(this).css("background-        image","url('gfx/plus2.png')"); });
$('.gamebox_minimap_plus').mouseup(function() { $(this).css("background-image","url('gfx/plus1.png')"); });
```

Comment: express youre love by voting up :)